# Text inside a div drop down together on jquery drop down menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement a simple jquery drop-down menu into a site working from this example - http://bhoover.com/simple-jquery-mobile-menu/

I have successfully done so however I wanted to change the way the drop down content appears on click of the toggle, if you look at the example demo in the link above you see that on click the drop down menu appears with the text content fixed and the div simply expanding to reveal the text. I however would like to have the text and the div which has a background colour applied to it to all drop down together, i know its to do with my positioning but not sure what I need to do. Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Below is my current code:

HTML:

```
<div id="toggle-bar">
    <h2 class="alignCenter"><a class="mtoggle" href="#">More</a></h2>
</div>
```

```
<article class="a-all moreArticle">
  <div id="mobile">
    <div id="mmenu">

      <section class="a5 alignCenter menuDropPadding">
        <h2><a href="">Header</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="">Header</a></h2>
      </section>

      <section class="a6 alignCenter menuDropPadding">
        <h2><a href="">Header</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="">Header</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="">Header</a></h2>
      </section>

      <section class="a7-a8 alignCenter menuDropPadding">
        <h2><a href="">Header</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="">Header</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="">Header</a></h2>
      </section>

      <section class="a9-a10 alignCenter menuDropPadding"> 
        <h2><a href="">Header</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="">Header</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="">Header</a></h2>
      </section>

      <section class="a11 alignCenter menuDropPadding">
        <h2>Header</h2>
        <h2>Header</h2>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#mmenu").hide();
    $(".mtoggle").click(function() {
      $("#mmenu").slideToggle(500);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You're nearly there, I used a position absolute div and positioned top: 0px; on the menu .click func I used Jquery animate to make it slide down I hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there, I used a position absolute div and positioned top: 0px; on the menu .click func I used Jquery animate to make it slide down I hope this is what you're looking for

jquery example

```
$(function() {
    $(".menuclick").click(function(){
        if($(".menuslide").css("top") == "60px"){
            $(".menuslide").animate({"top" : -700}, "slow");
        }else{
            $(".menuslide").animate({"top" : 70}, "slow");
        }
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLr26p7L/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put slideToggle(1200) and set margin left:50px for #mmenu like that

Answer (score 0):

I think this fits what you've described. The menu is  hidden by setting it to `top: -300px` and having the `.container` hide it with `overflow: hidden`. Then clicking on the `.toggle-bar` animates the menu's `top` while also animating the `.container`'s height.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="toggle-bar">Click me!</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item">Item 1</div>
        <div class="item">Item 2</div>
        <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.toggle-bar {
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.menu {
    background-color: #eee;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -300px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
var menuH = $('.menu').height();
$('.menu').css('top', -menuH);

var animating = false;

$('.toggle-bar').on('click', function () {
    if (!animating) {
        animating = true;
        if ($('.menu').css('top') == (-menuH) + 'px') {
            $('.container').stop().animate({'height': menuH + 30});
            $('.menu').stop().animate({'top': 30}, 500, function () {
                animating = false;
            });
        } else {
            $('.container').stop().animate({'height': 30});
            $('.menu').stop().animate({'top': -menuH}, 500, function () {
                animating = false;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/4x6grsdt/).

Comment: Thats pretty much a copy of my answer but then you put a little more time in the jquery animation.

Comment: @StijnBernards It follows the same principle, yes. Mine has the added advantage of being able to be put anywhere on a page, since it doesn't interfere with the flow of content above it. So it could for example be placed under another banner at the top of the page, or even in the middle of the page to reveal more content if needed. Mine also doesn't stop working if the user clicks on the bar rapidly.

Comment: @StijnBernards Actually I just looked at your answer again and it behaves quite differently from the example that was given. Yours does not push down the page's content. Maybe that's what the OP wants, but maybe not.